# Rendering artifacts with GUI application in WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-22.04

I see the following artifacts when moving the mouse over Linux applications running in WSL:

[image]

The system is a Thinkpad T470 (Intel Core i5-7300U CPU, integrated graphics).  The installation ISO was downloaded directly from Microsoft. This is how I installed WSL:

In Windows

```
wsl --install
wsl --install Ubuntu-22.04
```

In the WSL shell:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo apt install x11-apps
```

WSL version:

```
WSL version: 2.0.9.0
Kernel version: 5.15.133.1-1
WSLg version: 1.0.59
MSRDC version: 1.2.4677
Direct3D version: 1.611.1-81528511
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.22631.2715
```

What could cause this?  This does not happen on other machines where I installed WSL.

Comment: [Edit] your question to include what versions of the WSL kernel and WSLg you are using

Comment: You could ensure WSL is updated by running `wsl --update`.

Comment: Provide your .wslconfig so we can understand how your WSLg environment is configured

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the Intel Graphics driver was not installed on Windows and solved the issue. Download can be found [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/search.html#q=i5-7300u&sort=relevancy&f:@tabfilter=%5BDownloads%5D&f:@stm_10385_en=%5BGraphics%5D).